# justgage, Jquery Accessing object again or completely redraw?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, justgage

I have an application which gets a Json feed from a Web.API system and populates it into a gauge JS object using [justgage](http://justgage.com)

the code which renders my gauges is as follows:

```
var address = "http://localhost:51799/home/getperfdata";

$.getJSON(address, function (data) {
    DrawGraphs(data);
});

var inc = 1;
function DrawGraphs(data) {
    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
        //console.log(val)
        //Draw the Divs onto the page!
        $("#targetdiv").append("<div class=\"col-sm-2\"id=\"g" + inc + "\"></div>");

        //Create a new Graph for each div we drew.
        var i = new JustGage({
            id: "g" + inc,
            value: val.Value,
            min: val.MinValue,
            max: val.MaxValue,
            title: val.SystemName,
            label: val.ItemName,
            levelColorsGradient: false
        });
        inc++;
    });
}
```

My problem is, I want to then re-call the Web API for updated details every 30-60 seconds, however I don't know how I could reference the objects to provide a new "value"..

The system is built so it will create a gauge for each Json object it is provided(so the view will just draw the amount being provided via Json) however this approach seems to of made it harder to re-reference the objects...

A Simple solution would be to "rip down and recreate" it every 60 seconds, Heck, I could even put a page refresh in place! but I feel this is a little..."hacky" and a more elegant solution should be developed if possible?

Comment: Hi @LShetty, although your solution worked, it has caused the page to redraw all the objects in addition to the existing objects.. is there a way of wiping the page and then re-drawing?

Comment: Use `$("#targetdiv").html(` instead of `$("#targetdiv").append(` to have just one object.

Comment: @LShetty switched on console.log i looked at the console it wasn't wrtiting only once per 60 second(i only have 1 json object at present) and when i inspect the DIV element I can see the Id property on the DIV being created within the JS increment up in an endless loop kind of way.(<div class="col-sm-2"id="**g999**">

Comment: Because it is an endless loop as you wanted to refresh every 60 seconds! When do you want to stop/break the refresh loop?

Comment: No, I mean in the space of 3-4 mins(it should only be 4 refreshes at this point) it has incremented the DIV id to "g2000"odd... and filled the console to an unmanageable amount of entries.